# Nested List and For Loop

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
list = 2*[2*[0]]
for y in range(0,2):
  for x in range(0,2):
    if x ==0:
      list[x][y]=1
    else:
      list[x][y]=2
print list
```

Result:

```
[[2,2],[2,2]]
```

Why doesn't the result be [[1,1],[2,2]]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are creating a list that is two references to the same sublist

```
>>> L = 2*[2*[0]]
>>> id(L[0])
3078300332L
>>> id(L[1])
3078300332L
```

so changes to L[0] will affect L[1] because they are the same list

The usual way to do what you want would be

```
>>> L = [[0]*2 for x in range(2)]
>>> id(L[0])
3078302124L
>>> id(L[1])
3078302220L
```

notice that L[0] and L[1] are now distinct

Comment: yep! try list = [[0,0],[0,0]] instead.

Comment: Whoa. I was debugging this thing for a while, and it didn't seem to make sense. I added print statements, and it outputted the right values, but I didn't think that it would be like that!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to save space:

```
>>> [[x,x] for x in xrange(1,3)]
```